# Overload resolution ambiguity: public final operator fun inc()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have error building with kotlin when i use method `inc()`

my snippet code like below

```
var id : Int = 1
        for (element in iframeElements) {
            val src: String = element.attr("src")
            Timber.d("YOUTUBE LINK: %s", src)
            if (src.contains("youtube")) { // i.e https://www.youtube.com/embed/16Sn1UQ95Ec
                val idYoutube = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, src.length)
                val videoInfo = YoutubeVideo()
                videoInfo.setVideoId(idYoutube)
                videoInfo.setId(id as Long)
                videoInfo.setImageUrl(getUrlforYoutubeThumbnail(idYoutube))
                lsYoutube.add(videoInfo)
                id = id.inc() // THIS PART ERROR
            } else if (src.contains("instagram")) { // i.e https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs421mHgPM4/embed
//String ig = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));F
                Timber.d("ig %s", src)
                lsInstagramUrl.add(src)
            }
        }
```

[image]

i am really confusing which part should i fixed? Or how to make increment number (Integer) with Kotlin. Does my code incorrect?

Comment: `id.toLong()` instead of `id as Long` and `++id` instead of `id = id.inc()`

Comment: @IR42 wow, its working now. Thank youu

Comment: @Tenfour04 there is in `setId()` call